# ios twitter OATH integration not working

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter

I am using Oath authentication in my ios app for twitter integration.

It was working fine earliar but now when I authenticate user then it sends me on this page. Whats going wrong. is there any change in API?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using older API that stopped working So now you have to go for new Solution.

Apple Introduced Social Framework that Allows Facebook, Twitter sharing without doing much more & with less efforts.

use [This](https://github.com/viezel/TiSocial.Framework).

Hope this will help.